# Generic index.php with different keywords

Tags: php, google-ads-api

I have a generic index.php that uses `$_GET` variables to display different pages, but the same time it displays different keywords for different pages.

We received a Google Adwords Landing page violation notice today, but they don't say what exactly we did wrong, can this feature that I did for the keywords as described like above violate Google's policies and cause them to ban this domain?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to gain an advantage by tailoring your page's keywords based on a `$_GET` parameter then yes, I can see why Google will feel you have violated their policies.

If you have different pages (i.e. home, news, events etc.) then give them URLs like `www.domain.com/news/`, `www.domain.com/events/` or `` `www.domain.com/news.php `` and `www.domain.com/events.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've followed and stuck to all their guidelines and I'd suggest you also use a [.htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/htaccess.html) to differentiate pages:

[Landing page and and site policies](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=28439&topic=30210)

[Overview of landing page quality](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113575)